# Bootstrap 3 tabs - calling MySQL Database in PHP for type ahead function - not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead

I am using bootstrap tabs for displaying a search box in tabbed format. I am trying to call mySQL backend to get the list of items for the searc box. For some reason it is not working. Can someone help by looking at the code ?  Look at the JS function in bottom. Why is it not calling ?

```
<div class="row ">  
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3" >
            <form class="form-inline" name="searchForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="" method="get">


                <div class="form-group">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
                      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#company" aria-controls="company" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Company</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#city" aria-controls="city" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">City or Zipcode</a></li>
                      <li role="presentation"><a href="#jobtitle" aria-controls="jobtitle" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Job Title</a></li>
                      </ul>
                </div>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="company">
                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                 <div class="input-group">
                                       <input class="form-control " type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText" value="Enter Company Name"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Company Name')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Company Name';">
                                           <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                <select id="searchYear" name="searchYear" class="form-control">
                                                        <option value="14" selected="selected">2014</option>
                                                        <option value="13">2013</option>
                                                        <option value="12">2012</option>
                                                        <option value="11">2011</option>
                                                        <option value="10">2010</option>
                                                        <option value="09">2009</option>
                                                </select>
                                          </div>

                                 </div>
                                 <BR>

                                <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Search</button>

                            </div>
                      </div>
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="city">
                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                         <div class="input-group">
                                               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchCity" id="searchCity" value="Enter US City or Zipcode"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter US City or Zipcode')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter US City or Zipcode';" >
                                                   <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <select id="searchYear" name="searchYear" class="form-control">
                                                                <option value="14" selected="selected">2014</option>
                                                                <option value="13">2013</option>
                                                                <option value="12">2012</option>
                                                                <option value="11">2011</option>
                                                                <option value="10">2010</option>
                                                                <option value="09">2009</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                  </div>

                                         </div>
                                 <BR>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
                                <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Search</button>
                            </div>

                      </div>
                      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="jobtitle">
                            <div class="form-group"> 
                                         <div class="input-group">
                                               <input class="form-control" type="text" name="searchJobTitle" id="searchJobTitle" value="Enter Job Title"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Job Title')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Job Title';" >
                                                   <div class="input-group-btn">
                                                        <select id="searchYear" name="searchYear" class="form-control">
                                                                <option value="14" selected="selected">2014</option>
                                                                <option value="13">2013</option>
                                                                <option value="12">2012</option>
                                                                <option value="11">2011</option>
                                                                <option value="10">2010</option>
                                                                <option value="09">2009</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                  </div>

                                         </div>
                                 <BR>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="search">
                                <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Search</button>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
        </div>  
    <div> <!-- search box row div offset -->

    <!-- row 3: ads top most box, only shown in desktops and not shown in mobile-->
    <!--div class="row hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <img src='ad.jpg'/>
    </div-->

    <!-- New row set: Data display -->



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            //autocomplete
            $(".searchText").autocomplete({
                source: "/h1b-visa-sponsors/search.php",
                minLength: 3
            });             

        });
        $(function() {

            //autocomplete
            $(".searchJobTitle").autocomplete({
                source: "/h1b-visa-sponsors/searchJobTitle.php",
                minLength: 3
            });             

        });

        $(function () {
            $('#myTab a:first').tab('show')
        })

    </script>
```

Comment: Are you seeing error in your console browser? if there is any error, possible your javascript code...

Comment: No error in the console browser :(   I think it has something to do with the bootstrap tabs. I took out everything and just placed form with input elements ( only one set) and it worked.  Does having 3 sets of the same input boxes with same ID in different tabs makes difference ?

Comment: `id` attribute have to be unique for each element.

Comment: @Kumar. As the comment above. `id` attribute need to be unique. You can use `class` attribute in case there any styles that needs to be defined in all your elements.

Comment: phillip, @bcesars you mean to say I cannot have the ID searchText in three different places right ?  I tried changing that too, no luck. I am trying to troubleshoot, as soon as I place the textbox in bootstrap tab-content section, it is not working...something to do with tabs in bootstraps I am guessing.